# How to display JSON data inside render as table in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, html-table

I am using an API which returns JSON of various different key-value pairs. I am trying to display them inside of `render()` as a table of 2 columns, key and value, with object keys and values in them, respectively.

1. The API in `fetchBasicDetails()` is POST which takes default this.state values as input and returns the JSON output.
2. The JSON Output object is then stored to **birth_details** property of this.state using `setState` method.
3. Then, I tried to show the object data in `<table>` tags using `forEach` and Object.keys, which shows nothing at all.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
export default class HoroscopeReport extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      day: 11,
      month: 2,
      year: 2019,
      hours: 12,
      minutes: 59,
      tzone: 5.5,
      lat: 19.22,
      lon: 25.2,
      birth_details:{}
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //console.log("Received user submitted data"+JSON.stringify(this.state))
    this.fetchBasicDetails();
  };

  fetchBasicDetails() {
        let myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        let urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
        urlencoded.append("day", this.state.day);
        urlencoded.append("month", this.state.month);
        urlencoded.append("year", this.state.year);
        urlencoded.append("hour", this.state.hours);
        urlencoded.append("min", this.state.minutes);
        urlencoded.append("lat", this.state.lat);
        urlencoded.append("lon", this.state.lon);
        urlencoded.append("tzone", this.state.tzone);

        let requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: myHeaders,
          body: urlencoded,
          redirect: 'follow'
        };

        fetch("https://json.astrologyapi.com/v1/birth_details", requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(result => {
            this.setState({ birth_details: result });
          })
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
       }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
{/* FORM SUBMITTION CODE HERE */}
              <h2>Output:-</h2>
              <table border={2} cellPadding={5}>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Key</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  Object.keys(this.birth_details).forEach(function (element) {
                  return <tr><td>element</td><td>this.birth_details[element]</td></tr>;
                  });
                </tbody>
              </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For reference, This is the output of JSON:-

```
{"year":2019,"month":2,"day":11,"hour":12,"minute":59,"latitude":19.22,"longitude":25.2,"timezone":5.5,"gender":" ","name":" ","seconds":0,"ayanamsha":24.124044280610406,"sunrise":"10:19:50","sunset":"21:47:13"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually rendering elements based on an array in React is handled with `map()` instead of `forEach()`. The reason is with `map()` you can manipulate each elements meanwhile iteration and return a completely fit **JSX** syntax for `render` method. In the same time `forEach()` does not return anything, only `undefined`.

I guess you can try the following:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Output:-</h2>
        <table border={2} cellPadding={5}>
           <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Key</td>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              {
                  this.state.birth_details && 
                  Object.keys(this.state.birth_details).map(function (element) {
                     return <tr>
                       <td>{element}</td>
                       <td>{this.state.birth_details[element]}</td>
                     </tr>;
                  });
              }
           </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice you posted an answer! Downsides of posting on mobile, I guess :o)

Comment: @cubrr No issues, that happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you need to use curly braces in JSX to indicate that you want to render the value, not the code as text as-is.

You'll also want to use `map` instead of `forEach`. `map` is used for transforming an array to something else (we're taking a list of strings and mapping them into React elements), whereas `forEach` is used to just do something with each element and not return anything.

Additionally, you probably meant `this.state.birth_details` instead of `this.birth_details`>

```
<tbody>
{
  Object.keys(this.state.birth_details).map(function (element) {
    return (
      <tr key={element}>
        <td>{element}</td>
        <td>{this.state.birth_details[element]}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  })
}
</tbody>
```

I've also set the `key` on the returned element. Read more about lists and keys in React [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: While this definitely helps to print the object data, it is however printing it character-wise! That is, the output in key value columns is like ```0 {, 1 ", 2 y, 3 e, 4 a, 5 r```

Comment: @VaibhavDwivedi In your code where you make the fetch, change `response => response.text()` to `response => response.json()`.

Comment: This parses the JSON for you, since currently you're just taking the JSON as a string and not an object.